# My GUI will not display when I hit run in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When I select "run" in Netbeans, my GUI does not display.  It just displays a box on the bottom of the screen that says "Build successful".

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package modelrange;

import javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel;

public class RangedModel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    DefaultBoundedRangeModel myModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RangedModel().setVisible(true);
            }
       });
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form RangedModel
     */
    public RangedModel() {
        myModel = new DefaultBoundedRangeModel(123, 100, 0, 1000);
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */

    private void initComponents() { 
    This is just the automated netbeans code from the GUI builder (edited out for the post)            
    }
```

Comment: Your `main` method has nothing in it

Comment: I used a main method from another GUI I built, but it still does not display

Answer (score 2):

1. `JPanel` forms are *not* created with `main` methods, in GUI Builder, which you *do* need.
2. `JPanel` is not a top-level container, which you *do* need to run a Swing app.
3. A top-level container is, for instance, a `JFrame`. So you should have created a `JFrame` form instead of a `JPanel` form. When you do this in Netbeans GUI Builder, a `main` method will be provided for you.
4. A simple fix would be just to create a new `JFrame` form, then just drag and drop the `JPanel` form to the `JFrame` form, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435), get rid of the `main` method in your `JPanel` form, then run the `JFrame` form class.
5. You may also need to set/change the Main class to the new `JFrame` form you just created. You can that by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601920/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are extending JPanel, it's wrong because as peeskillet wrote at points 2 and 3.
Kind of top-level container are:

- JFrame : the window with the bar
- JWindow : the window without bar
- JDialog : the window usually used to create option window

So you have to extend one of them, probably the first.

Than in this top-level container you can create JPanel, one or more, everyone will be a container of another object which will be the contenent.

Morover, remember to `setVisible` every JPanel that you implement and also the top-level container.

Useful links:

- [icon in JButton is not shown at the running of the program, what could be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709997/icon-in-jbutton-is-not-shown-at-the-running-of-the-program-what-could-be)
- [Java Swing: multiple windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655294/java-swing-multiple-windows)
- [What's the difference between the implements & extends keywords in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494380/whats-the-difference-between-the-implements-extends-keywords-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

change JPanel to JFrame. It will work.

Comment: Please see the comment from  Steve Kuo

Comment: even nothing in main. It will work. Because your constructor do all your GUI

Comment: But who calls the constructor - also by default, a `JFrame` constructor doesn't add components to itself or show itself, so I hardly think it would make a difference.  Besides, you shouldn't need to extend from `JFrame`, you're not adding any functionality to, simply create an instance and add the `RangedModel` to it...

Comment: user3301269 Please try and than share the resulting GUI.

Comment: I added the main method I've used from another GUI I built, but it still does not display.  Changing it to JFrame did not work either btw

Comment: constructor automatically invokes when object is created. initcomponents have the code you designed using NetBeans which is inside the constructor. try to create a new JFrame and design from first. if the you dont want to design again, add the already designed JPanel to JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Follow path YourProject/packacge which your java file is in
then,
You can right click to your project then click from over there "run file".This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in NetBeans, after building, check that you are running the file you need from the project. To do this, press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>